# Is it possible to collect arrows as items automatically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to send a signal (only occasionally) across a wide chasm to a floating island, without connecting anything directly to it (which rules out simply running redstone to it). I'm thinking one way to do it might be with arrows: if I can shoot an arrow far enough, I can detect it with a pressure plate or tripwire.

I'd prefer not to have to refill the dispensers with arrows. Is it possible to collect the shot arrows as items and hopper them into a chest?

Comment: Does running water over it work? I haven't played minecraft in ages, but for some reason I think that used to do something like that

Comment: @Ender Not when you're at work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrows as entities cannot be automatically be collected; only a player can collect them.

If creative mode is available, there are two ways I can think of to accomplish this:

- Use command blocks: You can use the `testfor` command to meet the requirements and trigger whatever it is you're triggering. There wouldn't be a need for arrows or dispensers with this method if you're testing for player position.
- Create a skeleton grinder: If you have a hopper feeding into the dispenser with a skeleton grinder on top, the arrows would never run out (especially if you keep at least one arrow in each slot, so bones and bows are not collected).

Comment: If your doing it in creative mode, you might as well just summon a redstone block at the target destination. This is the most strait forward way to "wireless redstone" using command blocks.